# Direct to move turtle to a specific spot

Tags: netlogo

I have enclosed turtles in between walls and obstacles and want them to move to a specific goal spot. Each tick I forward turtle only a specific amount. How do I implement this in terms to variating the turtle heading?
Explaining more
[image]

In the above figure:
1. Consider all turtles inside the box at the start
2. You want turtles to reach goal spot above,(where turtles present currently in figure)
3. You have obstacles that is, walls in between which 1 opening that is the rectangle in the figure with the gap. Turtles have to pass this gap only.
How I tried
I make turtles face the goal spot using facexy and bounce back after colliding with wall but in doing so the turtles on extreme left and right of box keep colliding with wall since after each collision they again have the direction from facexy

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but you may wish to look at `patch-ahead` and `heading` in the NetLogo Dictionary.  To take a trivial example, an unsophisticated algorithm would have a turtle set a new random heading whenever `patch-ahead 1` is an obstacle.

Comment: Check now please. Kindly inform if any part of problem is not clear.

Comment: It seems turtles are in two states (in the box, or out of the box). Turtles in the box should try to get out.  Turtles out of the box should try to approach the goal. (If the goal can be behind the box, you'll have to deal with that as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix (according to what I read about making the turtles bounce).

- goal-xcor is the x-coordinate of goal.
- goal-ycor is the y-coordinate
  of goal.
- random-number is a random number between 1 and 10(?).

  ```
      `If COLLISION: `
  ```
- **if they're in the left** make them `facexy goal-xcor + random-number goal-ycor`
- **if they're in the right** make them `facexy goal-xcor - random-number goal-ycor`

If there is not any collision it means they're in the right way and they should keep going the goal direction.

It's important that you `facexy goal-xcor goal-ycor` every time you make them turn around. To be more clear: Pseudo-code:

```
1 setup-turtles-inside-box
  loop:
2 ask all turtles to face goal.
3 ask all turtles to go forward.
4 if collision
5   if turtle-in-left
6       ask turtle to face goal-xcor + random-number goal-ycor
    else
        ask turtle to face goal-xcor - random-number goal-ycor
7 loop until all turtles are in goal.
```

Let us know of any doubt!

Here is another approach: 
http://rur-ple.sourceforge.net/en/random.htm